# Convert a Numpy array into a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, concatenation

I have a Pandas Dataframe (`dataset`, 889x4) and a Numpy ndarray (`targets_one_hot`, 889X29), which I want to concatenate. Therefore, I want to convert the `targets_one_hot` into a Pandas Dataframe.

To do so, I looked [at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938932/how-do-i-convert-a-numpy-array-into-a-pandas-dataframe) [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54982378/how-can-i-construct-a-pandas-dataframe-from-individual-1d-numpy-arrays-without-c) [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235180/efficiently-creating-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-numpy-3d-array). However, these suggestions are about smaller arrays, for which it is okay to write out the different columns.

For 29 columns, this seems inefficient. Who can tell me efficient ways to turn this Numpy array into a Pandas DataFrame?

Comment: What about `pd.concat((dataset, pd.DataFrame(targets_one_hot)), axis=1)`?

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I didn't put the pd.DataFrame in front of 'targets_one_hot'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can wrap a numpy array in a pandas dataframe, by passing it as the first parameter. Then we can make use of [**`pd.concat(..)`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate the original `dataset`, and the dataframe of the `target_one_hot` into a new dataframe. Since we here concatenate "vertically", we need to set the `axis` parameter on `axis=1`:

```
pd.concat((dataset, pd.DataFrame(targets_one_hot)), axis=1)
```